# Unable to read the keys in app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My program is not able to read the keys that are in the app.config file which looks like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" />
  <add key="webpages: Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <!--Email settings-->
  <add key="TOADDRESS" value="myMail@host.com" />
  <add key="PASSWORD" value="password" />
  <add key="SMTPHOST" value="asmtp.host.com" />
  <add key="SMTPPORT" value="587" />
  <!--End email settings-->
</appSettings>
```

The C# code this is to read the App.Config looks like this:

```
public PartialViewResult SendMail(EmailModel model)
    {
        string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SMTPHOST");
        int port = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SMTPPORT"));
        string receiver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TOADDRESS");
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("PASSWORD");

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(host, port);
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(receiver, password);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        MailMessage mailMsg = null;            

        try
        {
            mailMsg = new MailMessage(model.from, receiver, model.subject, model.body);
            smtp.Send(mailMsg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendErrorMail();
        }

        return PartialView("_About");
    }
```

I have also tried to use curly brackets, like so: `string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPHOST"];` but this doesn't work either.
However, if I hardcode the values in the C# code, and NOT use the App.Config, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

I am getting an error saying that the smtp host was not found. If I manually type in the smtphost, I get an exception on the other values, as a null reference on the `TOADDRESS`etc. I will get a null reference on all the values/keys that are in the App.Config

Comment: This looks correct. Are you receiving an error?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I edited my post

Comment: ASP.NET uses web.config, not app.config

Comment: are you using vs code? or vs